# ASP.Net Environment.NewLine stops working half way through a script?

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, newline

I'm using a script to construct an email, and half way through the NewLines just quit working. I don't see any errors, nor do I can any when it's executed.

Here is the code:

message = message & "Zoning Selections -" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine

```
message = message & "Standard Report: " & Request.QueryString("chkList0") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "Summary Zoning Report: " & Request.QueryString("chkList1") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "Executive Summary: " & Request.QueryString("chkList2") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "ZIP Report: " & Request.QueryString("chkList3") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "Custom Report - Individual Products: " & Request.QueryString("chkList4") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "Certificate of Occupancy: " & Request.QueryString("chkList5") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "Building Code Violation: " & Request.QueryString("chkList6") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "Code Compliance Violation: " & Request.QueryString("chkList7") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "Fire Code Violation: " & Request.QueryString("chkList8") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "Saftey Code Violation: " & Request.QueryString("chkList9") & Environment.NewLine
message = message & "Condemnation Report: " & Request.QueryString("chkList10") & Environment.NewLine

message = message & "Property Use: " & Request.QueryString("property_use") & Environment.NewLine
```

and here is the output:

Zoning Selections -

```
Standard Report: yes
Summary Zoning Report: yes
Executive Summary: yes
ZIP Report: yes
Custom Report - Individual Products: yes Certificate of Occupancy: yes Building Code Violation: yes Code Compliance Violation: yes Fire Code Violation: yes Saftey Code Violation: yes Condemnation Report: yes Property Use: Office
```

As you can see, the NewLine works until half way through, and then it simply prints everything on the same line. (also, the other NewLines were added to the file at another time than the ones printing correctly)

What am I missing?

### EDIT

Apparently the plain-text formating of an email break all Environment.NewLine line breaks for the rest of the email when it encounters a line longer than 40-50 character (I was using Outlook 2013).

My solution was simple, switch to HTML format and use 
 tags for line breaks instead.

Comment: How do you output the result?

Comment: The output is sent in an email.

Comment: And that email is sent as plaintext, not HTML body?

Comment: Correct. It is plain text currently. I have about 100 lines above the visible code that all use Environment.NewLine and function perfectly fine. For some reason it stops working after the "ZIP Report" line shown above.

Comment: Actually it looks like it starts to happen after "Custom Report - Individual Products:" what happens if you comment that entire line to skip it as a test?

Comment: I tried commenting out various lines earlier, and it seems no matter which lines I comment out, anything after Custom Report just won't place a NewLine.

Comment: Which email client are you reading results in? If possible could you try a different one (e.g. Instead of Outlook, GMail online etc.)

Comment: It appears that it begins to break on lines longer than 40 characters. That's weird. I'm going to try switching to HTML format email.

Comment: Good idea, I was going to suggest that. You will have more precise control over line breaks in that case

Comment: Thank you for your time. Switching to HTML fixed it.